# which cloud db solution should I choose for fulltext search?

Tags: database, cloud

For my UWP and android apps, I started my project using firestore DB to store some user addresses and some business data, approximately 1M users data. Unfortunately, I missed to know in advance, that [it does not support full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568142/google-firestore-query-on-substring-of-a-property-value-text-search/61516548#61516548). What I mean is, if I search "pha", it should return "ele**pha**nt" as a result of a search query. But it does not support this type of search. So now searching for another cloud db solution. Please help me to choose a cloud DB that is able to query with full-text search. What I mean for Cloud db is a database, that is offered by Google-like companies, like the ones [mentioned here](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases).

Note: I preferred the (firestore)no-SQL DB only because of the running cost of cloud SQL.
Google says Cloud SQL pricing is composed of the [following charges](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#cpu-mem-pricing):
CPU and memory pricing, Storage and networking pricing, Instance pricing

My users don't access my cloud-db every hour, If I choose Cloud SQL, I think I may have to pay for CPU charges, every hour, throughout the billing period, though my users use it or not. This is not the case with firestore DB. So I chose firestore db. Other than that. No other specific reason. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is "some"? 10, 1000, 1M or 500M? How much data is involved? How much do you pay at the moment? How many users do you have? How many users access the database simultaneously? As I read the question at the moment, you are the only user. In such a case, you could pretty much use any database.

Comment: What does "cloud" mean to you? A wise saying is that the cloud is just someone else's PC. What do you expect from "the cloud", except that there is a database that you can access?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, Thank you for your questions. I've updated my question. Yes, currently I am the only user, my project is in the development phase, but after the project is published to the store, my users count would be around 1M. Around 100000 users would upload or download data simultaneously. But the users count would gradually increase.